# React - Error when importing node package (Object prototype may only be an Object or null)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I am trying to implement this library with my React applicaiton however, I get an error when I import the package.

Error - TypeError: Object prototype may only be an Object or null: undefined

Package - https://www.npmjs.com/package/dukascopy-node

I tried importing it both ways, using require and using import from however it gives the same output

Function

```
import { getHistoricRates } from "dukascopy-node";

export const getHistoricalData = async (
  instrument = "btcusd",
  from = new Date("2018-01-01"),
  to = new Date("2019-01-01"),
  timeframe = "d1"
) => {
  try {
    const data = await getHistoricRates({
      instrument: instrument,
      dates: {
        from: from,
        to: to,
      },
      timeframe: timeframe,
      format: "json",
    });

    console.log(data);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error", error);
  }
};
```

Comment: on which line is the error occuring?

Comment: Directly on import, the only thing I have this this import { getHistoricRates } from "dukascopy-node";

I am not even calling the getHistoricaRates function

Answer (score 0):

As the import statement looks OK, there must be something wrong with your packages. I would try to delete the node_modules folder and reinstall all packages.
This is my go-to solution in such strange, unexplainable cases with imports.

Comment: I tried that a couple times but it's still the same. Could it be because of some weird reason where I can not install some not Node packages on React? Could you be kind enough to give it a try and see if it works for you, please?

Comment: I'm getting following error, I think the problem is in the package, but not sure about that.
../../node_modules/dukascopy-node/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js:22:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'
Did you mean './fs'?
Requests that should resolve in the current directory need to start with './'.
Requests that start with a name are treated as module requests and resolve within module directories